# GameObject switches between null and as value

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i run this code i expect a Diamond clone to spawn with 33% every 0.1 second UNLESS the Diamond is null. But what i get in the log is something like this

> Diamond!
>
> Diamond is null
>
> Diamond is null
>
> Diamond!
>
> Diamond!

How can Diamond switch between being null and not being null? There is nothing else in the scene. Im just doing it to try stuff out. Is there something about the Instantiate i dont understand?

```c#
public GameObject Diamond;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnDiamond",  0.5f, 0.1f);
}

void SpawnDiamond()
{
    if (Random.Range(0,2) == 0)
    {
        if (Diamond != null)
        {
            var newDiamond = GameObject.Instantiate<GameObject>(Diamond);
            newDiamond.transform.position = transform.position;
            print("Diamond!");
        }
        else
        {
            print("Diamond is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how is Diamond set and do you have more objects with this script attached than one? Also, is Diamond set from a prefab or from a Gameobject?

Comment: I don't know anything about Unity or C#, but it seems pretty like you continuously run a function that creates a branch depending on the random number. One branch creates a new GameObject and prints "Diamond", the else branch just prints "Diamond is null" without creating a new GameObject. This is exactly what I'd expect to happen. Tell me if I'm wrong cause I don't even know about this.

Comment: @Zebrafish Look again.  "Diamond" and "Diamond is null" is in the same branch. If the random number is zero, there is a check if diamond is null. Otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: @Doh09 Diamond is set in the editor with drag and drop. Its a prefab in a folder. There are no other scripts in the scene.

Comment: @Zebrafish your understanding of that piece of code is nearly correct. But the field Diamond  is never changed in the SpawnDiamond method. So the behavior is - strange

Comment: @Doh09 SORRY! There was a duplication of the script which explains everything. Im stupid. Thanks for bringin that to my attention.

Comment: @Lautaro You could post and accept this as an answer. Maybe some day another users faces a similar problem. You could save that person some hours :)

Comment: Since it was the answer I added it as such for clarity when others see this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have more objects with this script attached than one? A duplicate script perhaps?

A duplicated script, which hasn't that field set, via the Editor, could cause that debug log.

Comment: I hope you don't mind. that i proposed an edit that adds the actual explanation in addition to the questions, cause that was missing to make this a real answer.

Comment: The shame will be with me for the rest of internet! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Lautaro, happens to the best of us :)